# Getting error HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown method' (405 expected) for using Appium with class AndroidTouchAction

Tags: appium, appium-android

I using Appium for automation mobile chrome browser on a real device. I need to swipe on a webelement. I have used below script for  it

```
 AndroidTouchAction action = new AndroidTouchAction (driver);
        action.press(PointOption.point(00, 00)).moveTo(PointOption.point(100, 100)).release().perform();
        System.out.println("Test");
```

I got the below error in eclipse after execution

> INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown
>   method' (405 expected)

So the swipe operation is not completed. What is wrong here?

Below are the Appium logs

> [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.performTouch() with args:
>   [[{"action":"press","options":{"x":0,"y":0}},{"action":"moveTo","options":{"x":100,"y":100}},{"action":"release","options":{}}],"a6425cfd-df0b-490e-a30c-a3ef8c5b3424"]
>   [W3C] Encountered internal error running command:
>   NotYetImplementedError: Method has not yet been implemented [W3C]
>   at AndroidDriver.callee$0$0$
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\touch.js:136:11)
>   [W3C]     at tryCatch
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
>   [W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke]
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
>   [W3C]     at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function)
>   [as next]
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
>   [W3C]     at invoke
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
>   [W3C]     at enqueueResult
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:185:17)
>   [W3C]     at new Promise () [W3C]     at new F
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\$.export.js:30:36)
>   [W3C]     at AsyncIterator.enqueue
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:184:12)
>   [W3C]     at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
>   [W3C]     at Object.runtime.async
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:209:12)
>   [W3C]     at AndroidDriver.callee$0$0 [as performTouch]
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\build\lib\commands\touch.js:375:30)
>   [W3C]     at
>   C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\basedriver\driver.js:296:26
>   [W3C]     at tryCatcher
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
>   [W3C]     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:510:31)
>   [W3C]     at Promise._settlePromiseAt
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:584:18)
>   [W3C]     at Promise._settlePromiseAtPostResolution
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js:248:10)
>   [W3C]     at Async._drainQueue
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:128:12)
>   [W3C]     at Async._drainQueues
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:133:10)
>   [W3C]     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate]
>   (C:\Users\chints\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js:15:14)
>   [W3C]     at runCallback (timers.js:789:20) [W3C]     at
>   tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5) [W3C]     at processImmediate [as
>   _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5) [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/a6425cfd-df0b-490e-a30c-a3ef8c5b3424/touch/perform 404
>   7 ms - 4202

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you are using latest stable version of Appium server 1.9.1 and Java client 6.1.0.

Now when swiping, don't start from `x: 0, y: 0`.

Try starting from `x: 5, y: 5` instead.

This should work since Appium causes issues when starting from the border of the device.